# error downloading from Firebase Storage

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-storage

I am trying to download an image I uploaded to firebase 
I am passing the download url as httpPath.But `E/StorageException(16586): StorageException has occurred.
E/StorageException(16586): Object does not exist at location.
E/StorageException(16586):  Code: -13010 HttpResult: 404
E/StorageException(16586): StorageException has occurred.
E/StorageException(16586): Object does not exist at location.`

```
Future<Null>downloadFile(String httpPath) async{
    final Directory appDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    final appDirPath = appDir.path;

    final RegExp regExp = RegExp('([^?/]*\.(jpg))');
    final filename = regExp.stringMatch(httpPath);
    final File thefile = File('${appDirPath}/$filename');

    final StorageReference sref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('storeFolderName').child(filename);
    final StorageFileDownloadTask fileDownloadTask = sref.writeToFile(thefile);
    final int byteNumber = (await fileDownloadTask.future).totalByteCount;
    print('your file byte number is : $byteNumber');
}
```

Comment: Maybe file doesn't exist at the 'sref'. Make sure the regular expression is giving the required output file name

Comment: i am also facing same problem after implement firabase-messaging with different error code, same worked previously without any issue (Code: -13000 HttpResult: 0), any workaround on this